# Run Babel again after Webpack combines everything?

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I have this:

```
  {
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    include: [APP_ROOT],
    exclude: [path.resolve('./node_modules')],
    use: {
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      options: {
        plugins: [],
      },
    },
  },
```

If I don't exclude `node_modules`, it'll throw `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'`. However, I don't trust that every package is transpiled properly. Therefore, I want to run everything through Babel again after Webpack combines everything.

My understanding is that `babel-loader` runs Babel on each file individually. This causes the error above. If I run Babel on the whole output file, it works fine. Preferably, I'd want to run Babel on the output before Uglify/Terser.

How do I do this?

Comment: Have you tried this: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4039#issuecomment-419284940 That `Cannot assign to read only property` issue happens when things are misconfigured.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try those. Your comment was hidden by default, I missed it despite opening the thread several times.